# Mindstorm RIS 2.0 installation on Windows 10

Tags: mindstorms, rcx

I recently bought a RIS 2.0 but was unable to install the program onto my laptop running Windows 10 (now). I tried it on my office computer running Windows 7 and the installation was successful.

The error message was that (something like) the IR Tower cannot be installed and there was a "- 5" at the end of the error message.

Appreciate if someone can help enlighten me please!

Comment: As far as I recall, the drivers for the IR Tower are [32bit only](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1527/56) which may be part of the issue - would this explain the difference between the two machines?

Comment: Also, there's a couple of good suggestions on [this answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/6586/56), especially the link to [Installing LEGO Mindstorms on a Windows 7 PC](http://www.legomindstormsrobots.com/lego-minstorms/lego-mindstorms-ris-windows7/)